# How to use the headphones jack to send data to a circuit board in WP7 or WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, serial-port, arduino, .net-gadgeteer

I just wanted to know if there is a way to send data through Headphones Jack to a circuit board like arduino or a custom circuit board that handles serial communication or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF?**

This is possible, but there are quite a few caveats - all of these grouped around the fact, that audio playback, and by extension the headphone jack are not exclusive resources.

- The sound to encapsulate the payload must have excellent recognisability
- The sound must be extremely unlikely to be contained in any "normal" phone sound
- the receiving board must have good discrimination against "wrong" frequencies
- The above properties reduce the achievable bandwidth to a few baud

Additionally, sinve the connection is simplex, you should consider idempotency and send every command twice or more to increase reliability.

**HOW?**

Just play back the correct sounds in the correct sequence to send a command (maybe idempotently repeating), have the receiving board decode the sounds and act accordingly.

We did this successfully with Android, but I don't think there should be any difference with WP, as playing a sound file is a very basic operation.

Four our implementation (On/Off for N devices), there were N+4 different precreated sounds:

- "start command"  - if played, while a command is running, this resets the command logic
- N times "select device" - to be played after "start command"
- "on" / "off" - to set the command
- "execute" - to finalize

All of these can be repeated without side effects.

Comment: My next question will be How to do that.